# How to compare date and time in sqlite which is stored as text?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a column in sqlite database which stores date and time in this format(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM). When i try to compare this column with another date and time value my app crashes. I guess its because of the colon present in (HH:MM). How should i do the comparison?

Query:

```
public Cursor fetchrDatetime(String dati) throws SQLException {

       String query = "SELECT * FROM reminders WHERE reminder_date_time=" + dati;
       Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);

       return cursor;
   }
```

Logcat:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "16": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM reminders WHERE reminder_date_time=2015-01-09 16:14
           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
           at apps.rwx.doctorremainder.RemindersDbAdapter.fetchrDatetime(RemindersDbAdapter.java:248)
           at apps.rwx.doctorremainder.ReminderEditActivity.saveState(ReminderEditActivity.java:306)
           at apps.rwx.doctorremainder.ReminderEditActivity.access$300(ReminderEditActivity.java:40)
           at apps.rwx.doctorremainder.ReminderEditActivity$5.onClick(ReminderEditActivity.java:203)
           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for `WHERE` should be between `'`.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM reminders WHERE reminder_date_time='" + dati + "'";
```

Comment: @Diwa Please accept this answer if it is correct :-)